# Simple Square Recognition in BufferedImage Java

Tags: java, image-recognition

I'm currently working on an image recognition software for the robotics club at my school, and one part really has me stumped: shape recognition. I need to be able to detect the squares in this image before I can try to detect the shapes in the arena.

I've looked up some libraries like JavaCV, but I couldn't really find something that suited my taste. As a reference, here is the image from which I'm trying to determine shapes

[image: File to check]

Comment: *"Simple Square Recognition"*  Nothing in image recognition is simple (though a powerful API might offer a simpler wrapper method), so that seems contradictory.  *"I couldn't really find something that suited my taste"*  Get it working in any one API, irrespective of flavor.

Comment: So far, I've tried brute-forcing it by checking if pixels are next to each other. But that doesn't generate a nice line anyway, as sometimes the width of the square is not exactly 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing something similar to your task but I needed to recognize classes (resistors, capacitors, etc.) of objects and what are their boundaries in a real black&white photo:

[image: B&W photo]

Basically, the method was something like this:

1. Preprocessing - correct contrast, brightness, erosion, dilation, median, etc. - this step can be adaptive to whole/part of the photo.
2. Segmentation - now find parts of the photo where there could be "something" with some threshold for area, pixel intensity, etc.
3. Characterize - for every found potential segment calculate some characteristcs - max length, area, W, M - determinants, etc.
4. Classify - There're several classifiers that checked if the given characteristic can be of this class, and if the answer is yes - what is the "distance" of the given characteristic to the ideal model characteristic. Classification was done using fuzzy logic inference.
5. And of course - for every successful classification take the best matches if they exist.

In your case - the simplest characterization of a square is to find out its area and the max distance between two points that belongs to found segment. And before it you should preprocess the image with ["closing" operation (dilation->erosion)](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/digitalimaging/russ/erosiondilation/index.html)

You could also create nice algorithm to recognize if a square is cut by a line (and remove that line - then recognize again) and check if a square is overlapped by other square, etc.

---

Personally, I don't know any library that do such complex things as `library.recognizeSquaresOnImage(params)`. You are provided with some useful methods to prepare an image for recognition - the core of your task - you must do by yourself.

Every recognition problem has its own peculiar features that can be used to narrow uncertain results in every step in "recognition pipelie". For example, in my task, I knew that objects are black on a fairly white background, and are more or less separated from each other, etc.

My project was written in C++ using OpenCV library and I was using OpenCV library for only reading/writing image and displaying it in the window - I wasn't allowed to used any other methods of the library.

As a reference how you could do it - [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/pdrzewin/opencv-recognition/overview) is the whole project. Even now it doesn't work perfectly - it needs some calibration of classificators.

To have a better grasp how it works on a higher level - take a look at [main.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/pdrzewin/opencv-recognition/src/940a46ea91b96f40b1ffdf06a038715def9c69cc/src/main.cpp?at=default) file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried applying the **[Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)**?

That seems to be what you need, as your squares have straight edges.